# can we detect when a dynamic image literal is not found?

Tags: swift

I'm getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION because Im letting the user specify new objects, but only built'in ones have images so far. This line is failing:

```
 imagePreview.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: key)
```

can we detect and gracefully hide the imageView when a dynamic image literal is not found?

Comment: `#imageLiteral` is not intended to use with dynamic `key`. Why don't you simply use `UIImage(named: key)` ?